# Android studio alt+F7 doesn't work anymore

Tags: android-studio

What to do?
I have some other Android studio project and the alt+F7 works ok.

I guess something got broken in this particular project settings.
Also a class that is in use is shown (hover mouse over class name) to be "Class XX is never used"

Should I do project clean "Invalidate caches / Restart" from File menu?
I don´t like that because loosing all file history but if that´s what it takes.. any idea?

Comment: what Alt-F7 supposed to do?

Comment: Selecting (with mouse) a class name or method pressing alt+F7 will show all usage of this types/method. Like e.g. where a class is sub classed

Answer (score 0):

Doing "Invalidate caches / Restart" from File menu fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's now ( <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> ). Find usage is in `Menu -> Edit -> Find Usage -> Find Usage`